# How to my mobile app automatically expire the content even being in offline mode?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

My customer make a request for their commercial app is to automatically expire the content after downloading into the device in 7 days, even in the following cases:
+ without the internet connection to connect and check the expired time from the server
+ stop the customer try to maliciously modify the time in their device to expand the expired time

When the content expired, it will be removed from the device and unavailble to watch any more.

After a few days researching on Google, I still not find out the appropriate approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just add an expiration date at the content when you download it? And then check if is expired or not locally, without any control server-side.

Answer (score 0):

There is a few suggestions but not of them is enough to cover all the cases maybe it will be useful if you combined them :

1- get the time based on the **last know-location**   .
2- get the **network time** so the user
    changing their device time wont matter (requires an internet
    connection)

Comment: I think the last-known-location might be an option, if the developer doesn't mine asking for GPS privileges in their app.  The network time doesn't seem to meet the question's criteria, since the user wants this to work even when / if the user goes offline.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a great solution to this.  You do have a couple of options, none of which are perfect.

**Option 1** - use date / time from last known location

This will require you to request GPS access in your application, which may concern users, if the app doesn't have a valid need for tracking the users' locations.  But basically get the last known position, and in the `Location` object returned would be the time as of that last location check.  Two things could prevent this from working 100%.  First, with newer version of Android, users can disable certain app permissions.  This means they could disallow GPS access to your app.  To combat this, you could check this on app startup and inform the users they cannot access any content unless GPS access is enabled.  Second, if the user has no GPS signal, the last known location may have been from days ago, meaning the "current time" will be frozen as of the last GPS signal.  Also, some devices don't have GPS chips, so this would not work for them.

**Option 2** - Try to detect system date / time changes by keeping a log of the date / time in your app.

Basically, this will take some work to keep track of the system date / time on each launch, as well as the duration of each session in your app.  With this log, you could compare to the current / date time and see if the user is rolling back the clock.  This wouldn't be perfect, as a smart user who understood your checks could roll it back to the closest time to the last time the app was shut down, but at least this would limit them to having access to the content for 7 days of run time.  Also, it would take a really dedicated person to keep track of / exploit your checks.  Most users would simply try to roll back their clocks to a past date and it would be simple to catch.  With this method, make sure you are capturing / storing all times in UTC time, so that time changes don't trigger a false fraud scenario.

**Recommendation**

Personally, I would use both options if you are OK with the GPS permissions on your app.  If available, and given permission by the user, use the last known location to get the time.  If that isn't available, or if the user has removed the permissions, use a local store of run date/times and durations as a fall back.